# Check if a commit is merged to another branch, and if so, what is the merge commit?

Tags: git, merge

Suppose a git repo has two branches, `master` and `test`. `commitA` is made on the `test` branch. I want to check:

1. Whether `commitA` has been merged to the `master` branch?
2. If so, what is the SHA of the merge commit?

I want to check these programmatically (not by using `gitk`).

Comment: `git merge-base --is-ancestor` for the first.  No easy answer I know of for the second without scripting.

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28180247/how-do-i-see-a-commits-path-through-git-history-or-how-it-got-in-the-current/28305568#28305568 actually.

Answer (score 0):

There's a tool called [`git-when-merged`](https://github.com/mhagger/git-when-merged) that was designed exactly for this use-case. After installing it,

```
git when-merged commitA master
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score -1):

By your example, the branch `test` is now at commit `commitA`.
So you can check where `commitA` has been merged into `master` by this command:

`git branch --contains test`

This should list all branches that contains `commitA`, check to see if `master` is in the list.

For getting the SHA of `commitA` type:

`git rev-parse test`

The SHA of the merge commit and the `commitA` itself are the same.

Comment: The SHA of commitA and the merge commit are definitely not the same